# perform case-sensitive query with Linq to sql?

Tags: linq

How do I force LINQ to SQL to make case sensitive comparison on the database side? When authenticating I need the password authentication to be case sensitive while the username to be case insensitive. The generated query does not make a distinction  the SQL server comparisons are case insensitive.

```
public Boolean checkLogin(string uname, string pwd)
        {
            DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext(RetrieveConnection());

            int count=(from c  in dc.Logins
                      where c.UserName == uname && c.Password == pwd
                      select c).Count();
            if(count>0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of comparison will be done on SQL side depends on used collation name. The default is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, where `CI` means case-insensitive. So all texts in the whole database are threated case-insensitive and this option can't be set on a table or column level. But why on earth do you save passwords in clear text within the database? Use a hash algorithm and a salt and save this. This can then be threaded case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach on this is not a very good one. Best approach would be to save all the usernames in the database with small letters using method `string.ToLower()`. Regarding password, maybe you should try some encryption method, not store strings as passwords in database. There are plenty simple encryption methods, so it's not really too complicated ( see`System.Crypthography`)